# Fedora 34: How do I stop the console going blank and reduce the screen resolution on a text only console?

Tags: fedora, console, screen-resolution

I have a Fedora 34 server edition connected to a TV. There is no GUI installed and I only have a text based console.

My problem is that the console will blank after some time (I think a screen saver is kicking in) and also the font size is too small to read.

I would like to disable the screensaver and reduce the screen resolution because the text is too small to read. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These are two separate questions. There's an answer to the first one (console blanking) over at SuperUser, here: https://superuser.com/a/154388/52715

Answer (score 0):

First locate your console fonts. They should live under `/usr/lib/kdb/consolefonts/`.
You should edit the file vconsole.conf which could be found `/etc/vconsole.conf`. Add or edit the line `FONT="xxxxxxxx"`.
Where `"xxxxxxxxx"` you should put any font that you like from the console fonts in the above location. Just note that any number that they have, it usually means their size... Logically the bigger the number the larger the font is.
And do not forget to edit your grub configuration file and add the `vconsole.font=xxxxxx` at the very end of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`.
Not feeling sure about the above....Then try out with the command `setfont <font-name>`. Again the name could be taken from any file from the above folder.